# Parsing error in bibliography when combining revtex + DOI + @incollection

Tags: bibtex, revtex, doi

When I try to cite an `@incollection` with a DOI using revtex, I get some nonsense in the output: `"emph "bibinfo-booktitle-` appear spontaneously.

Here's a minimal example:

I have the following test.bib file:

```
@incollection{cit,
  author={First Name},
  doi={10.1007/b95428},
  booktitle={The Great Book},
}
@article{cit2,
  journal={Important Journal},
  author={Second Name},
  year={2014},
  doi={10.1007/b95428},
  pages={5048},
}
```

Now let's cite these:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib,doi}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\begin{document}
Text \cite{cit,cit2}.
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

Compiled output:

[image: Using natbib + doi works fine]

Beautiful output, and clicking the blue links will send you to the DOI:

But what if we just use the revtex package (as is required for various journals)?

```
\documentclass[prb,aps]{revtex4-1}
\begin{document}
Text \cite{cit,cit2}.
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

We get this output:

[image: Revtex gives space]

Yucky! What is that `emph bibinfo booktitle`?

Here's the relevant line in the bbl file:

```
  in\ \Doi{10.1007/b95428}{\emph{\bibinfo {booktitle} {The Great Book}}}%
```

Why can't we parse this?
But we can parse the journal entry, because it doesn't have the `\emph` tag.
Any ideas?